# 3 ways SLI NVIDIA GTX 980 and 2 TITAN X

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I have a GTX980 in my setup and I am in the need of extension, especially in regards to GPU RAM (I use my PC for machine learning, so graphic output is not an important matter).
My question is, is it possible to make a SLI setup with a GTX980 and 2 TITAN X.
[This](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/faq#c16) link in nvidia faq says the two GPUs must have the same architecture.
And well, those cards are all GTX and based on this explanation, short as it is, it is supposed to work. But considering the price of the TITAN, I would like to be 100% sure :) I would appreciate any help

Comment: You could get 3 1080s for the price of 2 Titan Xs. Faster & cheaper.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks for the tip. I am actually prefering larger chunks of memory on GPUs which works better for my setup. Otherwise, especially price-wise, your are completely right.

Comment: Get the new Pascal-based TITAN X instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't SLI dissimilar GPUs.As such you can SLI the Titans or 980s but not a 980 to a titan

That said, if you're using the GPUs for machine learning, SLI is of limited use - its entirely meant for rendering. In this case you *ought* to be able to use the GPUs independently

I'm not that familiar with the *specifics* but the manual for ths software you're using would back it up.

TLDR: No SLI with different gpu models, *but* you shouldn't need to outside gaming.

Comment: thanks for the explanations. I am using Tensorflow on CUDA. I did some more reading and as you said, SLI is of no use for CUDA jobs. And appearantly this is the future of data communication in NVIDIA world:
https://www.nvidia.com/object/nvlink.html

Comment: nvlink is a 'replacement' for PCIe - a nvlink capable system would need to be built from the ground up. SLI is of no use here cause SLI essentially splits rendering between cards - you can simply run tasks seperately and dispatch them as needed.